# How to pass the curl --data option to ansible uri module

Tags: curl, ansible, uri

```
curl -k -X POST https://mylink/action -d username=admin
```

How can I re-write the curl above using ansible uri module? I was not able to find a way to pass in the data option (-d or --data) from curl above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example from the [URI module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/uri_module.html):

```
- uri:
    url: https://your.form.based.auth.example.com/index.php
    method: POST
    body: "name=your_username&password=your_password&enter=Sign%20in"
    status_code: 302
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  register: login
```

`body` is similar to `--data`.

Comment: Ok thanks, that worked; that was the connection I wasn't making... --data from curl becomes body in ansible. Worked Thanks.